# Proof of "$x^2 = a \mod 2^k$ must have 4 roots for odd numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm kinda lost in understanding how to prove that there must be 4 roots. 
The +1 and -1 are obviious bust as for the remaining two i do understand that
$x^2 = a \mod 2^k$
$4m(m+1) = 1 \mod 2^k$
$2^(k-2)|m(m+1)$
But i don't know how to move on from there. How does one arrive at the remaining two roots?
Also what is the proof that a must be equal to 1? That it can't be equal to any other odd number?

Comment: It is not true that $a$ must be equal to $1$. For instance, for $k=4$, it can be $1$ or $9$. In general, there are $2^{k-3}$ squares mod $2^k$ (not counting $0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* If $r$ is a solution of $x^2 \equiv a \bmod 2^k$, then so are $-r$ and $r+2^{k-1}$.

Comment: But that is the soluton itself, isn't i? I do not understand how to get there.

Comment: Or to be specific if we consider any odd value of a, then the 4 solutions should be r, -r, 2^(k-1)-r and 2^(k-1)+r. Am i correct on that at least?

Comment: @ZergOvermind, yes. One motivation is trying to answer the question: if $r$ is a root, when is $r+h$ also a root?

Comment: But how do i get to that? I know i need to go through the fact that it is congurent to 2^(k-2) but i don't see the conection between these two.

Comment: So if r^2 is congurent to `a` then h^2 should be congurent to 0? Do you mean that?

Comment: @ZergOvermind, yes. So for what $h$ do $2h$ and $h^2$ both vanish mod $2^k$?

Comment: $2^{k-1}=2^{k}$ but how to get rid of $2^{2k-2}=2^k2^{k-2}$?

Comment: Oh, i'm blind. Since it is congurent to zero the multiplication is also zero. But what would be the more proper conection of this to the proof? To make it more formal?

Comment: That wasn't very well worded. How to prove that only these four will be the roots? That there wont be any more then these 4?

Comment: @ZergOvermind, that's a different question... But all roots mod $2^k$ are also roots mod $2^{k-1}$

Comment: That's actually my goal here. Understanding how to properly formulate the proof. Well i did kinda formulate something thanks to your help. Just not very confident in it.I went with substituting the a as a square for $r+h$ and then using the steps you helped me with. Does that seem to make enough sense as a proof? $x^2-a=x^2-(r+h)^2$ and then solving from there